# How do I send props from one component to another component, outside the render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Subject:**  I'm coding a login system.

**Language or library:** React (16.8)

**Problem**: I have a component called LoginControl. Within this component, I want to access another component (outside the render) . Then I want to send the username to the other component with the help of props.

---

**LoginSystem.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Welcome from "./Welcome"

class LoginControl extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { username:"code", password:"blogger" },
        { username:"true", password:"codes" },
        { username:"furkan", password:"gulsen" }
      ]
    }
  }

  Control = () => {
    var username = document.getElementById("username");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");

    this.state.users.map( (user) => {
      if(user.username == username.value && user.password == password.value){
        <Welcome uName={user.username} /> // problem
        // props --> Welcome
      }
    })
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.Control}>Sign In</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginControl;
```

---

**Welcome.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

const Welcome = (props) => {
  return(
    <h2>WELCOME {props.uName}</h2>
  )
}

export default Welcome;
```

> **Error:** Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: What do you expect the `Control` method to do?

Comment: Your code looks a bit weird. But the answer to your question will be: use a state management tool, like React Context API, redux, Mobx or other. Here is a good blog post about state management in React applications https://blog.bitsrc.io/state-of-react-state-management-in-2019-779647206bbc

Comment: The if command checks the user name and password. If both of these are true, get the Welcome component. And it can transfer the user name with the help of props. but it returns error. I'm adding the error to the upper pane.

Comment: What do you mean by "get" the Welcome component? The only thing you should do with a component is to render it, but this is only possible in the render method.

Comment: BTW, this.state.users.map( (user) => {} ) should return a value at every iteration. You're not returning anything

Comment: @Remeus Seriously? Thank you so much. I've been working on this all morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not designed correctly.
I recommend backing up and going more slowly.
If you want to see your props going to Welcome and being displayed inside LoginControl, try the the below.

Please note, Radu Nemerenco is correct, you were not returning anything from your Control function.
Based on the design above, I would recommend finding a Youtube video on React Login or buying a React course from Udemy.com, they are great and pretty inexpensive.

```
import React from 'react'
import Welcome from "./Welcome"

class LoginControl extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { username:"code", password:"blogger" },
        { username:"true", password:"codes" },
        { username:"furkan", password:"gulsen" }
      ]
    }
  }

  Control = () => {
    return this.state.users.map( (user) =>  <Welcome uName={user.username} /> )
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        {this.Control()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginControl
```